# Couldn't add new property to objects in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript

Am trying to add a new field (sid) in each object in a JavaScript array:

```
dataset_sk_final = [
  {'id':0,'name':'Banking'},
  {'id':1,'name':'Home'},
  {'id':2,'name':'Travel'}
]
```

My output should be like -

```
dataset_sk_final = [
  {'id':0,'name':'Banking','sid':''},
  {'id':1,'name':'Home','sid':''},
  {'id':2,'name':'Travel','sid':''}
]
```

I tried using below code but its not working, what am I missing?

```
var dataset_sk_final1 = [];
object.keys(dataset_sk_final).foreach(function (key) {
  'sid' = ''
}
dataset_sk_final1.push(dataset_sk_final[key]);

alert('after assigning final:'+json.stringify(dataset_sk_final1),null,2);
```

Comment: What does your console show? First, it will error out on `object.keys`, which needs to be `Object.keys`. Second, it will error out on `'sid'=''`, which is invalid syntax and doesn't mean anything--what did you expect that to do? Third, it will error out on the `push` line, since you are referring to `key`, which does not exist in this scope. Also, not that this problem has nothing to do with JSON. It's just a plain old JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off in `Array` object there is no method `foreach` but there is `forEach` (`case sensitive`), second - to assign new property to `Object` you can use [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation) like `el.sid = ''` or [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) like `el['sid'] = ''` but not  `'sid'=''` because it is just `String`

```js
var dataset_sk_final = [
  {'id':0,'name':'Banking'},
  {'id':1,'name':'Home'},
  {'id':2,'name':'Travel'}
];

dataset_sk_final.forEach(function (el) {
  el.sid = '';
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(dataset_sk_final, null, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work?

```
for(var index in data_sk_final) {
    data_sk_final[index].sid = ''
}
```

so your example becomes

```
dataset_sk_final = [
  {'id':0,'name':'Banking'},
  {'id':1,'name':'Home'},
  {'id':2,'name':'Travel'}
]

for(var index in data_sk_final) {
    data_sk_final[index].sid = ''
}

alert('after assigning final:'+json.stringify(dataset_sk_final),null,2);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.